# Jwplayer video-orientation not working in firefox

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using jwplayer as video player. I am using stretching option to show video as they captured. In chrome browser this works fine but I am having issue in jwplayer in firefox.

my code is:

```
jwplayer("hd1-container").setup({
                file: 'www.abcd.com/video.mp4',
                width: "100%",
                stretching: "optimal",
                aspectratio: "16:9",
                autostart: true
            });
```

Screenshot:

In chrome

[image: JWPLAYER In chrome]

In firefox

[image: JWPLAYER In firefox]

Note: Video is in portrait as shown in chrome, In firefox it run as landscape. 
I dont know whats wrong in my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using `stretching: "uniform"` instead of `stretching: "optimal"`

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/